# Defining a topological relationship between two objects

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I am looking for a mathematical definition/description of the following relationship between two objects. It's similar to a knot (as in topology) but between two objects.

I've found a similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380479/in-topological-terms-how-would-you-describe-the-relationship-between-two-consec) except it's more specific to rings whereas I am looking at arbitrary objects.

Any ideas? Thanks!

[image: 2 interlocking objects]

Comment: Does http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number help?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks! That seems quite related - is linking number limited to curves? Can we use it for general geometry?

Comment: If the objects are $A$ and $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$, you are seemingly interested into the *isotopy class* of the embedding $A\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^3\setminus B$.

Comment: @PeterFranek does this class include the cases where A and B are separate (e.g., their bounding boxes don't intersect)?

Comment: @hotnAny $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, of course.

Comment: @Thomas The next question is: how can prove two objects have or doesn't have such relationship? (assuming objects are represented by vertices and triangles)